# updateOne returns "matchedCount": 0, "modifiedCount": 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to just update two fields using two criteria in updateOne method.
Let's say that I got a document like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("123"), "name" : "someName", "text" : "someText", "date" : "someDay"}
```

Then I have function that is responsible for this update:

```
static async updateSomething( id , someName, newText, newDate) {
    try {
      const updateResponse = await collection.updateOne(
        { _id: ObjectId(id), name: someName },
        { $set: { text: newText, date: newDate} },
      )

      console.log( id, someName, newText, newDate );
      console.log(updateResponse.matchedCount);
      console.log(updateResponse.modifiedCount);

      return **updateResponse**
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to update comment: ${e}`)
      return { error: e }
    }
  }
```

Then, when I'm finally calling thi function with:

```
updateSomething( 123, "someName", "new text that i want", "new date that i want")
```

My first log confirms that data matches, but next two logs returning 0.
And nothing has been updated.

Anyone knows what is it about?
I was looking in docs, syntax looks good, I was searching answer anywhere else, found non of this case.

Comment: Your syntax is fine, if `updateResponse.matchedCount` is 0 then clearly the query section of your update is not matching the document the way you expect it. It's impossible for us to debug this for you without seeing the document in the database and the values you're actually passing. Regardless I recommend you start by doing all the basic sanity checks. (make sure the item you want exists in the collection you're querying, etc)

Comment: You were right, there was no document matching to this query.
One of these fields was an object, so instead of querying : name: someName i supposed to query: "object.name": someName.

Answer (score 0):

```
//actual code output from the mongo shell
//you need to remove Object ID in the command and run the below code. it returns //matchedCount and  modifiedCount correctly
> db.test4.find();
{ "_id" : "123", "name" : "someName", "text" : "someText", "date" : "someDay" }
> db.test4.updateOne(
... {_id: "123", name:"someName"},
... {$set:{text:"new Text", date: "new Date"}}
... );
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.version();
4.2.6
>
```